# NGROK and Laravel - Can't load CSS and JS because paths are wrong

Tags: php, css, laravel, path, ngrok

I need to share my project progression with my client and found NGROK on the web. It is very simple to use but I'm unable to load CSS and JS because the paths are wrong.

To open my website I need to type

```
123456789.ngrok.io/projectName/public/PathToView
```

I'm calling my files like this

```
<link href="/admin/build/css/custom.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

How can I fix this?

Thanks

Comment: Not familar with ngrok... But you can view network in developer tools to see where it's _trying_ to load your JS/CSS assets from.

Comment: How do you load it locally? The paths shouldn't change between the two. You may need to edit your apache/nginx config to add your ngrok address as an alias.

Comment: @DanielShillcock It goes to Localhost root because I start the path with /

Comment: Im not familiar with NGINX

Comment: In `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/` is a file for your local domain. Edit that file with `sudo`, and update your `server_name` line. Mine says `server_name local.app ngrokID.ngrok.io;`

Answer (score 1):

Laragon has NGROK built in, I didn't knew that.

Just had to serve the NGROK and then Update Apache VirtualHost adding a Alias, working perfectly.